# Getting the xlabels to reflect the DataFrame column

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have the attached DF that I am trying to plot however, the xvalues are the index from the DF when I would want them to be the actual episode names. Any recommendations here?[DF pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKs3t.png)

Comment: Please see [ask], which specifically says no screenshots of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By first selecting the column from the DataFrame, and the plotting that you end up not "carrying over" those labels with you. You fix this two different ways:

1. plot from the DataFrame, not from the Series

```py
top_episodes.plot(x="EpisodeTitle", y="Viewship(MM)", kind="bar")
```

2. Alternatively, set the index to be the EpisodeTitle, and then perform your column selection/plotting.

```py
top_episodes.set_index("EpisodeTitle")["Viewship(MM)"].plot(kind="bar")
```